# How to iterate over a range of cells in Excel/VBA?

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

```
Dim works As Worksheet
Set works = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim txt As Variant

myrange = works.Range("C1:C9")

For Each txt In myrange
        If InStr(1, txt, "£", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print txt.Value                    '<..Object required err
            Debug.Print works.Range("C" & txt).Value '<..Object required err
            Debug.Print works.Cells(txt, 1).Value    '<..Object required err
            Debug.Print txt.Offset(0, 1).Value       '<..Object required err

    End If

Next txt
```

I'm trying to get the value of the cell that contains the "£" and then delete it . I'm getting `the object defined error in any case. I've tried 3 different options and still getting the error. I'm new to VBA and still learning. How can I fix this, and why am I getting the error?

Comment: Your variable txt is of type Range. So you don’t need to use it as a number reference. Instead of works.Range() = use this syntax: txt.value =

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JoeyGrant, I have tried txt.Value too and I'm  still getting the error.

Comment: Debug.Print txt.Value    <..object required error

Comment: You forget `set` in `myrange = works.Range("C1:C9")`. Your pasted code doesn't make sense. Please post the actual code.

Comment: thank you @AndréChalella, that fixed it. I did not put "set" before myrange = works.Range("C1:C9"). Can you please explain why you have to set ranges  = to..... but not some other variable.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the line `myrange = works.Range("C1:C9")`. It should have `Set` before it, like:

```
Set myrange = works.Range("C1:C9")
```

This way you ensure you are making a reference assignment, instead of a value assignment. Without it, you're telling VBA that you want the value of the cells to go in your variable. With it, you're telling VBA that you want your variable to point to that range.

Since you did not explicitly declare `myrange` as a `Range` object, VBA implicitly declared it `Variant` and treated it as a `String`. So, in the loop, `txt` was a `String` too, not a `Range` as you expected. Hence your error.

If you had `Dim myrange As Range` in the beginning, your assignment without `Set` would have failed and you'd have fixed it immediately.

But there's a simple habit that prevents this kind of error: in the top of your module, insert `Option Explicit`. This way, you have to explicitly declare **ALL** your variables, which means VBA won't assume they're `Variant`.

You can even make that automatic by checking the relevant option in `Tools > Options`.